# Visual Studio Code not working after KDE install

Tags: kubuntu, kde, visual-studio-code

I installed KDE with `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. Although most of my files are present, some programs cannot be found anymore. I tried running `code` from the terminal but I get `command not found`.

If I try installing it with `snap install code` I get

```
 snap "code" is already installed, see snap "help refresh"
```